# Series simplification

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, singularity-theory

I had three problems to work on and I was able to solve the third summation problem. The first two, I am having difficulty understanding as to how to proceed.

Here are the questions:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4^n};.$$

After using the series:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}};.$$

I get

> $$ \frac{4}{9} $$

Which is similar to result from Wolfram

I am not sure how to proceed on this one either:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - 4};.$$

I was able to solve the third one

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ln(n)}{n^3};.$$

For this problem, I referred to : [Series simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154176/series-simplificatoin/1154178#1154178)

for help and it helped me understand what steps I needed to do solve it.

Any guidance and help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
-SG

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1/n)}{3n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3n^3}=0$.

Comment: I used http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154176/series-simplificatoin/1154178#1154178 to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one,

see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms) to find $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty[a+(k-1)d]r^{k-1}=\frac a{1-r}+\frac{rd}{(1-r)^2}$$

Can you recognize $a,d,k,r$ here?

For the second,

$$\frac4{n^2-4}=\frac{n+2-(n-2)}{(n+2)(n-2)}=\frac1{n-2}-\frac1{n+2}$$

Set a few values of $n$

Comment: So for the first one:

Comment: @user40929, Set $a=k=d=1; r=1/4$

Comment: I get 4/9 when I use the formula mentioned in my question and it coincides with the Wolfram Answer, but I get a different answer when I substitute the values in your series. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am getting an indefinite answer for the second one when I expand the series. Would that match your calculation?

Comment: @user40929, Observe that the survivor terms are $$\frac1{-1}+\frac10+\frac12+\frac13$$. I think the sum should start with $n=3$